# How to insert a value to a particular row in a DataTable C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

Please help me with a code snippet to insert a value to a particular row which already exists in my DataTable .

```
DataRow myrow;
for (i = 1; i <= cnt2+1; i++)
{
    myrow = finalRprt.NewRow();
    for (j = 1; j <= lstSubName.Count + 4; j++) 
    {
       myrow[j] = "-";
    }
    finalRprt.Rows.Add(myrow);
}
```

Now I want to add a value to the  particular row depending on a condition. How can I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite vague. But you can for example use the [`DataRow.SetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353039%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension methid to set a field of a `DataRow`.

You can either use the indexer to get a row of a `DataTable` or use `Linq-To-DataTable` to find the rows you're searching for.

```
DataRow row = table.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(r => r.Field<int>("ID")==ID)
                   .Single();
row.SetField("Name", newName);
```

[Generic Field and SetField Methods (LINQ to DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386916.aspx)

Now you need a [`DataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx) to update your database (if you want).

Comment: Appology Tim, the code above given is just structure of the table.Also I want to add the table is completely empty. I want to insert a value to a particular row in the table depending on a condition.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still   not clear what you want. It's not a problem is the table is empty. What makes this row _particular_ and what is the _condition_?

Comment: I want some reports to be displayed on a gridview. So I have to use few other tables from the database. My coding is bit shakey and awkward and I got into such situation. Also I m bit new to C# development.

Comment: Sorry, but even your last comment does not clarify your requirement. What have you tried to update the DataRow, what has not worked?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble Tim, I am unable to explain properly. The code snippet u hv give is interesting, I can use it in other places. Thanks for ur response.

Comment: I have acknowledged your answer since I feel ur code snippet may be useful for others.